# Group by custom function in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, group-by

I have a table of people in which there may be duplicates.  My goal is to return a list of possible duplicates so that we can combine them into a new person.

I want to group by `first_name` and `last_name`, obviously.  However, if both person records have a defined `birth_date` and those dates differ, then I want to exclude the records, since odds are the people are different but happen to have the same name.

The other caveat is that in our system (which I inherited), the `birth_date` column is `NOT NULL`, and non-specified `birth_date`s are set to `'1900-01-01'`.

Is there a way I can `GROUP BY` a custom function (or use some other clever logic) that either compares just the `birth_date` columns checking to see if both are not the default date or they are if the same, or else takes in arguments, like say each `person_id` and compares the records against each other, returning a `BIT` to decide whether they should count as the same group?

I'd like to avoid CLR-defined aggregate functions (since I'm inexperienced with it).

So far (without the `birth_date` comparison) the query I have is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM core_person P
WHERE last_name + ',' + first_name IN 
    (SELECT last_name + ',' + first_name "name" 
     FROM core_person 
     GROUP BY last_name + ',' + first_name
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
ORDER BY last_name + ',' + first_name
```

I would like to add something to the `GROUP BY` clause to compare the birth dates.

Comment: Does your table have a ID column, or some other way to distinguish otherwise duplicate rows?

Comment: Thanks - missed that in your original question.  Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the nullif function to return nulls if the date is equal to 1/1/1900 as `nullif(Birthday,'1/1/1900')` to your advantage.

This query can get you started to see all the records with their possible matches:

```
select p1.person_id
from core_person p1
join core_person p2
on p1.person_id <> p2.person_id
    and LEFT(p1.first_name,5) = LEFT(p2.first_name,5)
    and LEFT(p1.last_name,5) = LEFT(p2.last_name,5)
    and isnull(nullif(p1.Birthday,'1/1/1900'), p2.Birthday) = isnull(nullif(p2.Birthday,'1/1/1900'), p1.Birthday)
group by p1.person_id
```

If either one of the Birthday's are equal to 1/1/1900 it will compare the birthday to itself, otherwise it will only join on equality of the birthday's in both records.

If you don't want to see your matches, you can use a variation of the query above as a sub-query to return only id values that are duplicates:

```
select core_person
from core_person 
where person_id in
    (
    select p1.person_id
    from core_person p1
    join core_person p2
    on p1.person_id <> p2.person_id
        and LEFT(p1.first_name,5) = LEFT(p2.first_name,5)
        and LEFT(p1.last_name,5) = LEFT(p2.last_name,5)
        and isnull(nullif(p1.Birthday,'1/1/1900'), p2.Birthday) = isnull(nullif(p2.Birthday,'1/1/1900'), p1.Birthday)
    group by p1.person_id
    )
```

Comment: Unfortunately, if either one of the birthdays is equal to 1/1/1900, I *do* want to return them, since it's possible the birthday just wasn't submitted on one of the record creations, but is, in fact, a duplicate of the person.

Comment: I believe this will work!  I'll check it as soon as I can (just about to leave) and if it works, I'll mark it as answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't the `having count(*) >1` along with the `p1.person_id <> p2.person_id` mean this only returns rows with 2 or more potential matches?

Comment: Ack... you're right.  It should be one or the other but not both.  I fixed the answer by getting rid of the having clause.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of grouping, will something like this work for you?

```
select * from MyTable a
left join MyTable b
on a.person_id < b.person_id 
    and a.first_name = b.first_name 
    and a.last_name = b.last_name
    and (
        a.birthdate = b.birthdate 
        or a.birthdate = '1900-1-1' 
        or b.birthdate = '1900-1-1'
        )
```

It matches rows where last name and first name match, and either birthdates match or one birthdate is your placeholder value.  The person_ID part of the join gets rid of duplicates (e.g. 1 matches to 2, then another row where 2 matches to 1, or 1 matches to 1).

You may want to broaden the match criteria for the names to look at first few characters or use `SOUNDEX`, but then your matches would probably require more hand-sorting as a final step.

Edit: to return a list of all records that have a possible duplicate in the table, not associated with their matches, use this instead:

```
select distinct a.* from MyTable a
inner join MyTable b
on a.person_id <> b.person_id 
    and a.first_name = b.first_name 
    and a.last_name = b.last_name
    and (
        a.birthdate = b.birthdate 
        or a.birthdate = '1900-1-1' 
        or b.birthdate = '1900-1-1'
        )
order by a.first_name, a.last_name, a.birthdate
```

Comment: How do you want to handle those cases?  E.g. if 1 matches 2, and 2 matches 3, but 1 does not match 3, do you want to return 1, 2, and 3 in a group?  In this case that would imply that 2 has the '1900' birthdate, but 1 and 3 have actual (and distinct) birthdates.

Comment: Can you post an example of your expected results?  I'm not sure I understand what you're looking for.  If you're just feeding in one specific person at a time, and returning duplicates for that person, then the question is a lot simpler than I thought.

Comment: I've edited my answer to add a solution I think matches what you're looking for.  Not sure, though, so let me know if I guessed wrong.